# How to write a pattern that matches the URL containing numbers?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm writing a crawler and it have to follow URLs like:

```
http://www.example.com/121-blah-blah
http://www.example.com/721-blah-blah
http://www.example.com/1512-blah-blah
```

But not URLs like:

```
http://www.example.com/category/1512-blah-blah
```

How should I write the pattern to do this? The path will be start with a number.

Here is what I got so far:

```
%r[(\d+]
```

Comment: Do you need to look for numbers only within the path part of the url or anywhere in the url?

Comment: @NicNilov only in the path part

Answer (score 2):

Parse the string into a URI object and apply regex to the path part only. Converting to URI has added benefit of additional checks such as `uri.absolute?`. It also takes care of various optional parts of an uri, such as port number or basic authentication values.

```
uri = URI.parse(your_string)
uri.path =~ %r{^/\d+}
```

The `^/` in regex makes sure the match is at the beginning of the string and after leading slash. `\d+` matches any number of digits. If you want a number match anywhere in the path, use this:

```
uri.path =~ %r{\d+}
```

A statement like this returns an integer meaning index of the first match or `nil` if there is no match.

You might want to check out [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) for tuning the regexes.

Comment: I want to match with url like this `http://www.example.com/1512-blah-blah`, But want to exclude URL's like this. `http://www.example.com/category/1512-blah-blah`

Comment: Then use `uri.path =~ %r{^/\d+}`, it will do just that.

Answer (score 0):

If the digits are going to be after "/" then the regex will be as simple as

```
regex = /\/\d+/
```

Then you can match this with the strings using the following

```
if regex =~ url != nil then # returns nil if no match else returns index of first character matched
```

Answer (score 0):

How about being a bit specific like this:

```
http[s]?:\/\/[\w\.]+\/\d[\w-]*
```

[See example](http://rubular.com/r/izEKTSZpFX)